# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject return null when cast to class

Tags: c#, json

i'm trying to cast a simple json string to my class

Json string

```
{"Title":"SQL","Connection":"","Command":"select * from tbl_roles"}
```

Class

```
public class EmailMessage
    {
        [JsonProperty("Title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Connection")]
        public string Connection { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Command")]
        public string Command { get; set; }
    }
```

C# Code

```
    EmailMessage emailMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(email.BodyText.Text.Replace("\r",string.Empty).Replace("\n",string.Empty)) as EmailMessage;
```

the variable returning null

the image of the watch of the Command

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(email.BodyText.Text.Replace("\r",string.Empty).Replace("\n",string.Empty))
```

[image: Watch]

Comment: The result of `JsonConver.DeserializeObject` is a plain `object`. And you cannot simply cast an object to `EmailMessage`, thus `somobject as EmailMessage` returns `null`. Use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmailMessage>(...)` instead

Comment: I hope you aren't writing software that accepts SQL commands by email, that sounds like a recipe for a major SQL injection disaster....

Comment: yes it is run sql via email and also return json object of the result

Comment: @MaherKhalil You understand the security implications of that? So literally everyone can send literally any query to your service via email and it's just executed?

Comment: Can you please show  the result of this  -   json = email.BodyText.Text.Replace("\r",string.Empty).Replace("\n",string.Empty))

Comment: @derpirscher Do you understand the security implications when everybody can use the web application?

Comment: @Serge Yes I understand them. Therefore I don't allow unsanitized inputs. And the way OP is currently coding, I doubt he is anyhow sanitizing the inputs ...

Comment: @derpirscher He is not asking your opinion and you are not a psychiatrist or you have selected the wrong resource. This resourse is for software developers. They  can  create any code they want or need.

Comment: @Serge Yes anyone can of course create any code they want. Nonetheless if someone is doing something potentially very dangerous, someone with more experience should at least drop a hint on how dangerous this is. For the same reason, on nearly any question which uses queries concatenated from strings instead of parameters the first hint is "use parameterized queries".

Comment: @I am sorry but I am getting sick already to read warnings about sql script injections in each post. Doesn't matter what this post about. There are some people that heard something about this and they put it each post.  They think they are very smart and nobdody else heard about this. It is time to stop it.

Comment: @Serge Maybe you were perfect from the first line of code you started to write. I wasn't and I made some (on hindsight) very dumb mistakes, and I would have been happy, having someone pointing out the implications to me.

Comment: @Serge *It is time to stop it* IMHO In the contrary. There are more and more very inexperienced users on SO which are working on projects way over their abilities. And they are all talking about "production" code, which means such bad code will sooner or later be out there, ready to be attacked. Most of them will only have implications within their own system. But other issues open the door to seize those systems, which may have implications on others as well.

Comment: @Serge By the way. the JSON string is fine. Otherwise it wouldn't be deserialized to an object, as you can clearly see in the last screenshot ...

Comment: @derpirscher first thank you for the first comment it was the correct answer please write it as an answer so that i can accept it - second yes i now the risk it is accepting emails from only one specific email address and the email should be written as json string as shown above so i do not thisnk it is a risk

Comment: @MaherKhalil the sender of an email can easily be spoofed. And even if the mailbody is a JSON string, it still can contain any query. What prevents someone to use `"Command": "drop table tbl_roles"` instead of `"Command": "select * from tbl_roles"`? I bet you've heard from little "Bobby Tables" https://chruezundquer.ch/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/exploits_of_a_mom.png I don't say, what you want to do is impossible. You just should think about the implications and take the necessary precautions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of `JsonConver.DeserializeObject` is a plain `object`. Well -- in your case -- it's a `JObject` actually, cast to an `object`. And you cannot simply cast an `object` (or `JObject`) to `EmailMessage`, thus `somobject as EmailMessage` returns `null`. Because that's how the [`as` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#as-operator) is defined.

Use

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmailMessage>(...)
```

instead. It will return an instance of the generic type parameter, or throw an exception, if the JSON string cannot be parsed to that type (or the JSON string is invalid in the first place)

Answer (score 1):

You create a variable for available JSON.

```
string jsonBody = //Prepare available json string here...
```

And use this code:

```
EmailMessage emailMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmailMessage>(jsonBody);
```